# Product Rule for vector output functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In Spivak's calculus of manifolds there is a product rule given as below.

if $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable at a, then

$D(f*g)(a)=g(a)Df(a)+f(a)Dg(a).$

My question is, if this condition of  '$f,g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$' is always necessary? What if we have vector valued output for each of the functions? Is there a generalized product rule? If not, how is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20694/vector-derivative-w-r-t-its-transpose-fracdaxdxt) answer valid because $x^T$ and $Ax$ are surely not satisfying above condition.

Comment: You have to be careful about the order of multiplicands so that the products make sense.

Comment: Is that the only thing to be concerned about? Can you suggest me some reading related to this?

Comment: See also XVII.3 Properties of the derivative (Product) in Lang's Undergraduate Analysis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're still interested, you can define a "generalised product rule" even when the target space of your functions is a vector space (it can even be infinite dimensional).

> **Theorem.** (See Loomis and Sternberg)
>
> Let $U,V,W, X$ be normed vector spaces. Let $g: U \to V$, and $h: U \to W $ be functions which are differentiable at a point $\beta \in U$. Let $\omega: V \times W \to X$ be a bounded bilinear map. With these assumptions, the composite function $F : U \to X$ defined by
>   \begin{equation}
> F(\xi) = \omega(g(\xi), h(\xi))
> \end{equation} 
>   is differentiable at $\beta$ and its derivative at $\beta$ (which is a linear map from $U$ into $X$) is given by the formula
>   \begin{align}
> dF_{\beta}(\cdot) = \omega(dg_{\beta}(\cdot), h(\beta)) + \omega(g(\beta), \tag{*}dh_{\beta}(\cdot)),
> \end{align}
>   i.e for all $x \in U$, we have
>   \begin{equation}
> dF_{\beta}(x) = \omega(dg_{\beta}(x), h(\beta)) + \omega(g(\beta), dh_{\beta}(x)).
> \end{equation}

As a remark, Spivak would use the notation $DF(\beta)$ to mean the derivative of $F$ at $\beta$, but I used $dF_{\beta}$ (as in Loomis and Sternberg), simply to avoid a lot of brackets when evaluating this linear transformation at a certain point $x$. But, aside from this slight notation change, in this formula, we like to think of $\omega$ as "multiplication"  so that $F(\xi)$ is the "product" of $g(\xi)$ and $h(\xi)$. Notice how the derivative formula (*) takes the nice form "differentiate the first keep the second $+$ keep the first, differentiate the second". To read more about this, I **HIGHLY** recommend the book [Advanced Calculus](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf) by Loomis and Sternberg. This theorem is in fact Theorem $8.4$ of Chapter $3$ (with slightly different notation).

---

**Addition in Response to OP's comment:**

Let $A \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$. Then, for $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$, the quantity $x^t A x$ can be written using the standard inner product of $\mathbb{R^n}$ as $\langle Ax, x \rangle$. So, what we're doing is considering the following functions (mimicing the notation above):

- $g: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^n}$, defined by $g(x) = Ax$
- $h = id_{\mathbb{R^n}}$.
- $\omega = \langle , \rangle$
- $F: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by
  \begin{align}
  F(x) = \langle Ax, x \rangle = \langle g(x), h(x) \rangle 
  \end{align}
  Note that $g$ and $h$ are both linear transformations so, for any $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$, we have $dg_x = g$ and $dh_x = h$. If this isn't clear to you, see [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246931/prove-pi-i-mathbbrn-to-mathbbr-such-pi-barx-x-i-for-every/3246958#3246958). Hence, by the formula above,
  \begin{align}
  dF_x(\eta) &= \langle dg_x(\eta), h(x) \rangle + \langle g(x), dh_x(\eta) \rangle \\
  &= \langle g(\eta), x \rangle + \langle g(x), h(\eta) \rangle \\
  &= \langle A \eta, x\rangle + \langle Ax, \eta \rangle \\
  &= \langle \eta, A^t x \rangle + \langle Ax, \eta \rangle \\
  &= \langle (A^t + A)x, \eta\rangle,
  \end{align}

where in the last line, I made use of symmetry and bilinearity of the inner product. Now, you may be wondering, since $F$ maps $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, how might we calculate its partial derivatives? The relationship is very simple (see the book I linked above, Section 3.8 for more details):
\begin{align}
(\partial_i F)(x) &= dF_x(e_i) \\
&= \langle (A^t + A)x, e_i \rangle
\end{align}
where $\partial_i F(x)$ is what you might normally write as $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(x)$, and $e_i = (0, \dots, 1, \dots, 0) \in \mathbb{R^n}$, with $1$ in the $i^{th}$ place.

Comment: Hello peek-a-boo. Please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766415/product-rule-for-vector-valued-functions. Here in his edit OP has mentioned product rule slightly differently. I suspect that this can be derived from what you have written here. But I am not able to get there. In my opinion what OP was doing originally was also correct and follows your answer. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @mw981 hi, I elaborated those calculations in this "formalism"

Comment: it was very helpful. Thank you.