# Finding the derivative of a linear map $Tx = x_1 -2x_2 + x_3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Let $T : \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear map (linear transformation?) $$Tx=x_1-2x_2+x_3.$$ Determine the derivative of the linear map and the matrix of it.

Apologies if I'm getting the name wrong. Wikipedia translated the page from my native language to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map).

The matrix is simply $[1,-2,1]$ right?

However to find the derivative we had some weird expression that I couldn't find on our course material which looks as follows $$T(x_0+h)-T(x_0)=Lh+||h||\varepsilon(x_0,h)$$

The $RHS$ reminds me of the numerator of the difference quotient, but I guess that's not what we're after here?

Edit:

Found the definition from our material apparently a function $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at a point $x$ iff there exist a linear mapping $T_x : \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$ and in some neighborhood of zero there is a function defined $\varepsilon(h)$ that satisfies $$f(x+h)-f(x)=T_x(h)+||h||\varepsilon(h)$$ and $$\lim_{h \to 0} \varepsilon(h)=0.$$

Comment: What is your native language ? do mean something like directional derivative ?

Comment: The derivative of every linear map is the linear map itself.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3246958/568204) to see why the derivative of a linear transformation is itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a function $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$ is differentiable at a point $x_0\in\mathbb{R^n}$ if there is a matrix $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x)=f(x_0)+A(x-x_0)+o(||x-x_0||)$ holds when $x\to x_0$. Then the matrix $A$ is the derivative of $f$ at the point $x_0$. You can think of it as the best approximation of $f$ by a linear transformation in some neighborhood of the point $x_0$.

Now, if $T:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$ is a linear transformation then there is a matrix $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $T(x)=Ax$ for all $x$, this is a standard result in linear algebra. It is not hard to guess that $T$ is differentiable everywhere, and the derivative is always equal to $A$ – after all, this is what we have in the theory of functions of a single variable. The multivariate case is not different.

But a guess is not enough, we want a formal proof. So let $x_0\in\mathbb{R^n}$ be any point. For every $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$ we have:

$T(x)-T(x_0)-A(x-x_0)=T(x-x_0)-A(x-x_0)=A(x-x_0)-A(x-x_0)=0$

And hence $T(x)=T(x_0)+A(x-x_0)+0$. The function $0$ is obviously $o(||x-x_0||)$ when $x\to x_0$ and so we indeed we have the required equality. The matrix $A$ is indeed the derivative of $T$ at the point $x_0$.

In your specific case the matrix which corresponds to your transformation is $(1,-2,1)$, so it is the derivative everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your $T$ is an example of a linear functional, a linear function/transformation which sends vectors to $\mathbb{R}$ (or another base field).

It's partial derivatives are just like the derivatives of other functions you've seen, like if $f(x,y,z) = 2x + y - z$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2$.

And its whole derivative will be its gradient, but interpreted as a linear map $L = \nabla T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Indeed it does, however, the expression is still a bit odd would you happen to know where it is coming from?