# Can someone recommend me a nice and rigorous proof of the change of variables formula?

Tags: integration, change-of-variable, diffeomorphism

By that, I mean the transformation formula for diffeomorphisms in integrals. Sadly, that proof was done very poorly in my analysis lecture and I want to see a rigorous proof.

Comment: How much background do you have? Measure theory? Did you look at the classic textbooks? Spivak, Munkres, Rudin, Folland etc? I've also written [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4224651/568204) on this site (using measure-theoretic arguments). It seems to me you need to search more.

Comment: Yes I have taken a measure theory course this semester.

Comment: See the link then.