# Differentials as linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, differential-geometry

I found the following on the [Differential (infinitesimal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(infinitesimal)) Wikipedia page. First they take a function $f(x)$ and define $x$ as the identity map of $\mathbb{R},$ such that $f(x(p))=f(p).$

> The differential $\mathrm{d}f$ (which of course depends on $f$) is then a function whose value at $p$ (usually denoted $df_p$) is not a number, but a linear map from $\mathbb{R}$  to $\mathbb{R}$...

There is more to the quote, but that's easily found on the Wikipedia page.

Anyway, let's say $f(x)=x^2.$ Then for some real $p,$ $df_p=2xdx_p.$ But I'm confused as to how this is a linear map. In particular, what is $dx_p$ here? The Wikipedia page mentioned it's "again just the identity map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (a $1\times1$ matrix with entry $1$). But it can't be saying $dx_p=\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}$, can it? So, what exactly is $df_p$ as the Wikipedia page describes?

Comment: Fix your $p$ to be something like $3$.  Then $df_3$ is the linear map multiplication by $6$ which does $x \mapsto 6x$, which is a $1 \times 1$ matrix containing $6$ as the only entry.

Comment: See [how does the idea of differential $dx$ work if derivatives are not fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4202312/568204) for the one-dimensional case. In that answer, I also link to another answer where I address the multivariable case. Anyway, to address is directly again: $x$ here denotes not a single point in $\Bbb{R}$, but rather the identity function $x:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, $x(a)=a$ for all $a\in\Bbb{R}$. Now, $dx_p=d(\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}})_p:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is the differential of the identity at the point $p$, which due to linearity simply becomes the identity again.

Comment: i.e $dx_p:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is the linear transformation given by $dx_p(h):=d(\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}})_p(h)=\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}}(h)=h$. and as for why derivatives of linear maps at any point are themselves, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3246958/568204). So, indeed, the matrix-representation of $dx_p:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is really just $[1]$. This shouldn't be too surprising because if for all $a$ we have $x(a)=a$, then of course, for every $a$, we have $x'(a)=1$ (the prime means the usual limit of difference quotients).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to elaborate on my comment just to address the specific example of $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, given by $f(p)=p^2$. Let us use $x:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ as the identity function. Then, one can write
\begin{align}
df&=2x\,dx
\end{align}
This is a super condensed notation. So, the first thing we must do is plug in a point $p\in\Bbb{R}$ for where we're calculating the differential. So, we have
\begin{align}
df_p&=2x(p)\,dx_p= 2p\,dx_p
\end{align}
Now, notice what everything is, $df_p:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is a linear transformation. On the right, $2p\in\Bbb{R}$ is a number, $dx_p:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is a linear transformation, so on the right we also have a linear transformation. Linear transformations must eat vectors in their domain to spit out vectors in their target space. In our situation, everything is close to trivial since $\Bbb{R}$ is a 1-dimensional space. So, for any $h\in\Bbb{R}$, we have
\begin{align}
df_p(h)&=\bigg(2p\,dx_p\bigg)(h)=2p\cdot dx_p(h)=2p\cdot d(\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}})_p(h)=2p\cdot\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}}(h)=2p\cdot h
\end{align}
i.e $df_p(h)=2ph$. This is the full effect of the differential when we plug in everything.

Also, you asked

> But it can't be saying $dx_p=[1]$, can it?

No, that's not what it says. As I've emphasized many times now, $dx_p=d(\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}})_p=\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}}$ is a linear transformation $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$. But from linear algebra I hope you're comfortable with the idea that once we specify a basis for the domain and target space, we can associate to any linear transformation, a certain matrix. In this case, we choose the basis $\beta_1=\{1\}$ for the domain $\Bbb{R}$, and also the basis $\beta_2=\{1\}$ for the target space $\Bbb{R}$. Then, the matrix representation (which I denote by square brackets around the linear transformation) is
\begin{align}
[dx_p]_{\beta_1}^{\beta_2}&=\begin{pmatrix} 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
This is simply saying that the matrix representation of the identity linear transformation (with respect to the same basis on the domain and target) is the $1\times 1$ identity matrix. Hopefully this is obvious from linear algebra.

Finally, I want to emphasize that saying for all $p$, $dx_p=\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}}$ or that for all $p$,  $[dx_p]_{\beta_1}^{\beta_2}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\end{pmatrix}$ is entirely equivalent to the statement that for all $p$, $x'(p)=1$.

---

Notice that in general one ends up (simply by unwinding definitions without any handwaving) that $df=f'\,dx$. This means $df_p(h)=f'(p)\cdot dx_p(h)=f'(p)\cdot h$.
So, as you can see, in one-dimension, the object $df$ doesn't tell us a whole lot; we're just multiplying by $f'$ at the appropriate point. The reason this was so trivial in one dimension is because linear algebra in one-dimension is trivial, not because the idea of the differential is trivial.

Comment: What's the context where differentials are studied like this? That is, would this be in a linear algebra course, or some other subject?

Comment: @mpnm This is the subject of differential calculus (it's usually intoduced in this manner only in higher dimensions) you can read books like Spivak's calculus on manifolds, or Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced Calculus (chapter 3 on Differential calculus, and chapter 9 on differentiable manifolds) to learn more. These two books though are generally regarded as more difficult. A much gentler approach can be found in Bamberg and Sternberg's Volume I (where they actually show how to do calculations with these things, and introduce many other applications)