# Is the derivative of the $ij$th entry of a matrix equal to the $ij$th entry of the derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

An alternative title to my question could perhaps be:*What is the derivative of the projection mapping?*

In any case, let $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be any matrix and consider the function $f(t) = \exp(tX), \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$. While working with matrix exponentials, I've come across the situation in which I'd need to evaluate $\frac{d}{dt}(f(t))_{ij} = \frac{d}{dt}(\exp(tX))_{ij}$ at some $t = t_0$, i.e. the derivative of the $ij$th entry of the matrix, but none of my reading materials address whether $\frac{d}{dt}(\exp(tX))_{ij} = \left(\frac{d}{dt}\exp(tX)\right)_{ij}$ as the presented proofs have not required this property.

I also couldn't find material addressing this online, so one idea I had to see whether the equality holds is to first view an $n\times m$ matrix as a $nm$-dimensional vector, so that $(\exp(tX))_{ij}$ is nothing but the projection onto the $ij$th coordinate: $(\exp(tX))_{ij} = \mathrm{pr}_{ij}(\exp(tX))$. Then, as $\mathrm{pr}_{ii}:\mathbb{C}^{n^2}\to \mathbb{C}, f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ I thought that I could apply the chain rule of multivariate functions to $\mathrm{pr}_{ii}\circ f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. But the issue with this approach is that at $t_0$ let $N = f(t_0)$, then by the chain rule of multivariate functions, $D_1(\mathrm{pr}_{ii}\circ f)_1(t_0) = \sum_{k=1}^{n^2}D_k\mathrm{pr}_{ii}(M)|_{N = M}D_1f_k(t)|_{t = t_0} = \sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial M_{ij}}\mathrm{pr}_{ii}(M)|_{M = N}\frac{d}{dt}(\exp(t))_k|_{t = t_0}$

In other words, I'm still stuck with the $\frac{d}{dt}$ w.r.t. the $ij := k$th entry of the $\exp(tX)$ matrix. So what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the derivative of matrices are the matrix of derivatives. Also, the (Frechet) derivative of the projection mapping at any point is itself, [because it is a linear transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3246958/568204) (i.e for any $A\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$, we have $D(\pi_{ij})_A=\pi_{ij}$ as an equality of linear transformations). In this regard, I would highly suggest you read [Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced Calculus](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eshlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf). It is an excellent text, and covers differential calculus in Banach spaces in detail (particularly sections 3.6 and 3.7 for the basics, and 3.8,3.9 to see how the general theory works out in $\Bbb{R}^n$, and also 4.8, which talks about Banach algebras, and exponentials).

So, in general, if you have a mapping $f:\Bbb{R}\to M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ (if you want you can replace $\Bbb{R}$ with $\Bbb{C}$, it doesn't change anything), then its derivative at a point $t$ is an element $f'(t)\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$. And just so you recall, this element $f'(t)$ is related to the Frechet derivative $Df_t:\Bbb{R}\to M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ as $f'(t)=Df_t(1)$ (this is essentially the isomorphism $\text{Hom}(\Bbb{R},W)\cong W$, $T\mapsto T(1)$, for any vector space $W$). So,
\begin{align}
\pi_{ij}(f'(t))&= D(\pi_{ij})_{f(t)}[f'(t)]\\
&=D(\pi_{ij})_{f(t)}[Df_t(1)]\\
&=D(\pi_{ij}\circ f)_t(1)\tag{chain rule}\\
&=(\pi_{ij}\circ f)'(t)
\end{align}
This equation is saying precisely that the derivative of a matrix-valued function is the matrix whose entries are the derivatives of those entries. In your case, you're just looking at the special case $f(t)=\exp(tX)$ for some fixed $X$.

And even more generally, if $V$ is any Banach space and you have a mapping $f:\Bbb{R}\to V$ which is differentiable at a point $t\in\Bbb{R}$, then for any $\lambda\in V^*$ (the continuous dual space), we have that $\lambda(f'(t))=(\lambda\circ f)'(t)$. THe proof is identical to what I wrote above; just replace $\pi_{ij}$ with $\lambda$ everywhere. This equation tells us that if we look at "a component" of the vector $f'(t)$, then that is the same as the derivative of "the component" at $t$, i.e $(\lambda\circ f)'(t)$.