# Fréchet Derivative of Inner Product

Tags: inner-products, frechet-derivative

If $ f:R \to H$ is the map such that $H$ is a Hilbert Space and $\langle f(x), f(x)\rangle =1$.

My problem involves differentiating the equation involving the inner product above to get a relationship between $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$.

Kindly help!! Thanks & regards.

Comment: $<f',f>+<f,f'> = 0$ --> $<f,f'> = 0$

Comment: What have you used @mathworker21 ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155664/product-rule-for-vector-output-functions/3244485 this answer of mine might be helpful for you. it's basically a generalisation of the product rule (the inner product is a bounded bilinear map so what I called $\omega$ in my answer can be replaced by the inner product)

Comment: Nice, Can you suggest any readings for the proof of the same? @peek-a-boo

Comment: proof of the "same"? do you mean product rule? if yes, then take a look at the book by Loomis and Sternberg which I referenced in that answer

Comment: Can I use chain rule, to find the desired Derivative as I know the Derivative of a bilenear form but for the arguments being independent variables??? @peek-a-boo

Comment: yes that's how this "product rule" is proven in the book I referenced. (pretty much any differentiation rule can be proven from the chain rule; for example sum quotient, product rules can all be derived from chain rule)