# How to evaluate $\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}(\boldsymbol{\theta^t \Phi^t})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Given the least-square loss function$$\boldsymbol{L}=||\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{\Phi\theta}||$$

where $\boldsymbol{\theta}\in R^{M\times 1}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Phi}\in R^{N\times M}$

Find $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{L}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}}$.

---

My attempt:

$$
\boldsymbol{L}=(\boldsymbol{y^T}-\boldsymbol{\theta^T\Phi^T})(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{\Phi \theta})
$$
By the multiplication rule:
$$
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{L}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}
=(-\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}(\boldsymbol{\theta^t \Phi^t}))(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{\Phi \theta})+(\boldsymbol{y^T}-\boldsymbol{\theta^T\Phi^T})
(-\boldsymbol{\Phi})
$$
How to find$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}(\boldsymbol{\theta^t \Phi^t})
$?

By intuition, $$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}(\boldsymbol{\theta^t \Phi^t})=\boldsymbol{A}
$$ where $\boldsymbol{A}\in R^{1\times N}$ with entries $\Phi_{i}$ corresponding to $\theta_i$.

How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer from other threads.
$$
\boldsymbol{L}=(\boldsymbol{y^T}-\boldsymbol{\theta^T\Phi^T})(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{\Phi \theta})
$$
By the correct usage of [product rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766415/product-rule-for-vector-valued-functions):
$$\rightarrow
(\boldsymbol{y^T}-\boldsymbol{\theta^T\Phi^T})
(-\boldsymbol{\Phi})+
(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{\Phi \theta})^T(-\boldsymbol{\Phi})
$$
where I used $$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}(\boldsymbol{\theta^T \Phi^T})=(\boldsymbol{\Phi}^T)^T
$$
by noting that the derivative of $v^T u$ with respect to $v_i$ is $u_i$ generalizing to $u^T$ for the gradient.

Or (im not sure) by another application of the product rule for the gradient of the product:
$$
\rightarrow \boldsymbol{0}+(\boldsymbol{\Phi}^T)^T(\frac{\partial }{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}((\boldsymbol{\theta^T})^T))
$$

---

The product rule **for the gradient of the product** specified above holds particularly for the case $v\cdot v$ where $v\in R^{1\times N}$.

I do not have a generalization for that method however this is sufficient for most of my needs.